# unable to push to git remote repository

Tags: git

I am new to git. when i am trying to push my code to my repository, i encountered an error. To solve it i removed index file. Because of that, i lost connection to my git repositorey. now i have changes in my local repository and i want to push my code to the remote repository. how can i do it without loosing the local changes. how can i connect to my remote repository and push my code. please guide me thanks.

error

```
fatal: index file smaller than expected
```

what i did

```
$ rm .git/index
$ git reset HEAD .
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to get the index file reloaded:

```sh
    git add .
```

Now try to push back using:

```sh
    git push
```

In case push doesn't work use this:

```sh
    git remote add origin https://github.com/example/repository.git --set-upstream
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DVRQoVRzMIY) video might help you better understand git.

Hope this helps!
Cheers